# Why does “missmutig” lack an umlaut when every other “-mütig” adjective has one?

Tags: adjective, umlaut, denominalization

There are lots of nouns ending in *∙mut*

> Schwermut, Wehmut, Langmut, Grossmut etc.

and lots of adjectives ending in *∙mütig*

> gutmütig, kleinmütig, wankelmütig, freimütig, reumütig.

So far as I can tell, every adjective constructed this way has an umlaut in *∙mütig* **except** *missmutig.*

Why?

Comment: searching in DWDS for "\*mutig" yields some more words, *anmutig, edelmutig, kampfesmutig, missmutig, todesmutig, wagemutig*, [see here](https://www.dwds.de/?q=*mutig) (I have no access to a rückläufiges Wörterbuch).

Answer (score 6):

The German word *Mut* has the meaning *courage, boldness, bravery:*

> **Er bewies Mut** und nahm die Herausforderung an.
>   **He showed courage** and accepted the challenge.

But it also can mean *mood:*

> **Frohen Mutes** machte er sich auf die Reise.
>   He embarked on the journey **in a happy mood.**

You find the second meaning even more often in compound nouns:

- Sanft**mut** = meekness
- Schwer**mut** = gloom
- Edel**mut** = generosity

Adjectives, that are derived from words of this second meaning end in *»∙mütig«*:

> sanftmütig, schwermütig, edelmütig, gutmütig, demütig, wehmütig

Adjectives, that are derived from the courage-meaning end in *»∙mutig«*:

> mutig, wagemutig, todesmutig, kampfesmutig

But there are also two exceptions:

- Anmut = grace, charm; **anmutig** = graceful, charming
- Missmut = displeasure; **missmutig** = morose, grumpy

(<del>*anmütig*</del> and <del>*missmütig*</del> do not exist)

Comment: You might want to mention "Mut" and "Gemüt" in your answer.

Comment: I think op knows it's an exception and asks why there is one. Also please note that anmütig & missmütig where used (as well) up until 16th to 18th century.

Comment: Yes, as @mtwde said this answer more or less restates the question. I'm aware that there is an exception (or two exceptions) but I'm wondering if anyone knows what explains the variance.