# (Jemanden + Adj + "zu" + Verb) Struktur

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure, infinitive, spoken-language

Ich habe eine Frage. Ist dieser Satz richtig oder klingt er für Sie komisch?

*Sein Mut macht ihn ein bisschen schwierig, zu tolerieren.*

Allgemein gesagt, ist diese Struktur akzeptabel?

*machen + jemanden + adj + zu + verb*

Danke Ihnen!

Comment: "Sein Mut macht ihn ein bisschen schwierig zu tolerien" ist zumindest ohne Komma auf jeden Fall ein korrekter Satz, das hat @Wolf ja schon beantwortet. Aber bedeutet der Satz wirklich das, was Sie sagen möchten? Der Satz bedeutet: Es ist schwierig für andere, ihn zu tolerieren, weil er soviel Mut hat. Warum? Ich verstehe den Satz inhaltlich nicht und ich frage mich, ob Sie vielleicht eigentlich etwas anderes sagen wollen, als der Satz jetzt sagt. Könnten Sie den Kontext erklären?

Comment: @HalvarF -- So, in English, "His mood made him a bit difficult to tolerate." vs. "His mood made it a bit difficult for him to tolerate." In both languages the impersonal pronoun is needed for the second meaning. The comma placement makes it "His mood made him a bit difficult, to tolerate." -- Wrong in English too.

Comment: @RDBury: ok, a confusion between "mood" and  "Mut" (totally different things) could indeed explain why the sentence sounds so strange.

Comment: @HalvarF -- Darn, I managed to understand most of this (the gist at least) while only looking up one word, and it's that word that I got wrong. Wiktionary has two definitions for *Mut*, "courage" and "mood". (DWDS seems to concur. Also [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/54031/43989)) I didn't think "courage" fit the context so I though it would be "mood".

Comment: @RDBury: Yes, using Mut for mood is possible in some idioms or contexts, and I wonder if that's also what the OP meant. However, it doesn't work like that without proper context. It would definitely only be understood as meaning courage in this sentence. A fitting word would be "Launen" here if mood is what is meant.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the discussion. 

Firstly about the comma: I have apparently made a mistake. (I'm a new learner and have obviously picked up something wrong). 

Secondly, about the meaning of "Mut", I meant "Courage" here. However, I'd like to be able to put any personality attribute here. That is, what I mean is: "His Courage [or Rudeness/Seriousness/Stinginess/Kindness] makes him difficult to tolerate", for example "because this courage somehow results in risky, dangerous actions".

Comment: @SaraShahmohamadi, to make it clear: the comma is not wrong here, it is optional and would be dropped by most writers for it is not needed.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Jetzt erst begreife ich, dass das obige Komma doch funktionieren könnte. Schließlich kann jemand auch *schwierig sein*. Dieser Grundaussage könnte dann eine Präzision folgen, die auch anders lauten könnte, z.B. "im täglichen Umgang" oder "zumindest anfänglich". Und im Bestand des Möglichen sind auch *einfache Infinitive mit zu* möglich. Dann entsteht zwar nicht die übliche Schriftform, wohl aber verschriftete Rede. Natürlich ist diese Deutung nicht die naheliegendste, aber gegen das Urteil "sinnentstellend", das meine Antwort einleitet, wäre nun eigentlich eine Revision fällig.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Thank you! Good to know! I try to look into these punctuation rules!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man kann das so sprechen, aber in Schriftform wirkt das Komma hinter *schwierig* sinnentstellend.

In geschriebener Form sind folgende zwei Varianten naheliegend.

Zum einen die bereits genannte ohne das Komma (da der Infinitiv mit zu *nicht* erweitert ist):

> Sein Mut macht ihn ein bisschen schwierig zu tolerieren.

zum anderen mit dem Komma, wobei das *ihn* die Seite wechselt (erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu) und ein *es* als grammatisches Subjekt hinzukommt:

> Sein Mut macht es ein bisschen schwierig, ihn zu tolerieren.

Ich muss eingestehen, dass mein Wissen darüber aus der Zeit vor den Rechtschreibreformen ab 1996 stammt und daher die Terminologie vielleicht schwerer belegbar ist, daher bleibe ich vorerst die kanonische Referenz auf "Erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu" schuldig.

[2.1 Komma: §74 Infinitivgruppen grenzt man mit Komma ab, wenn eine der folgenden Bedingungen erfüllt ist. - grammis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par75)

> [...]

> E2: In den Fällen, die nicht durch § 75(1) bis (3) geregelt sind, kann ein Komma gesetzt werden, um die Gliederung deutlich zu machen bzw. um Missverständnisse auszuschließen. Dasselbe gilt für Partizip-, Adjektiv- und entsprechende Wortgruppen (siehe § 77(7) und § 78(3)).

Im vorliegenden Fall ist die Abtrennung der letzten beiden Wörter für das Verständnis eher hinderlich, denn die Aussage hat m.E. eine Struktur, die sich so vereinfachen lässt, wobei sich lediglich der Grad der Tolerierbarkeit ändert (den jeweils geklammerten Ausdruck fasst die nächste Aussage durch ein Wort zusammen):

> Sein Mut macht ihn (ein bisschen schwierig) zu tolerieren.

> Sein Mut macht ihn (schwer zu tolerieren).

> Sein Mut macht ihn untolerierbar.

Nach §74 E2 wäre also vermutlich eine solche Kommasetzung tolerierbar:

> Sein Mut macht ihn, ein bisschen schwierig zu tolerieren.

Aber ich würde sie nicht empfehlen.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Könnte man nach der Logik dann auch schreiben _Spaghetti sind schnell, zu kochen_? Das kommt mir suspekt vor. Es schließt Missverständnisse nicht aus, im Gegenteil, und die Gliederung verhaut es auch.

Comment: Aber es geht doch nicht um Zeichensetzung, sondern um Grammatik?

Comment: @DavidVogt Kann man das sicher sagen? Aus der Frage werde ich immer weniger schlau. Die Überschrift legt folgende Assoziationen nahe (in Pseudocode): [Jemanden ~ (?), Adj ~ "schwierig", "zu ~ "zu", Verb ~ "tolerieren"], der Schluss der Frage hingegen folgende: [machen ~ "macht", jemanden ~ "ihn", adj ~ "ein bisschen schwierig", "zu ~ "zu", verb ~ tolerieren]. Kann sein, dass hier um Hilfe bei der Satzgliedbestimmung gebeten wurde, Ich hatte die Frage "Ist dieser Satz richtig oder klingt er für Sie komisch?" spontan als die eigentliche aufgefasst - und das Drumherumrum als Rechtfertigungsdekor.

Comment: @phipsgabler, nein, das kann man nicht. Ihr Beispiel enthält zwar eine Infinitivgruppe im Sinne der Grammatik, nicht aber im Sinne der Rechtschreibregeln. Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitivgruppe#Verh%C3%A4ltnis_zur_Grammatik_der_Infinitive

Comment: @Wolf Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort. Ich wusste nichts über diese Komma-Regeln. Ich habe bis jetzt nur die Form, die ich geschrieben habe, gesehen und dachte dass, es nur eine Variante gibt, deshalb habe ich den Satz so geschrieben.

Comment: @Wolf Ich glaube, dass meine Überschrift nicht genau/ausgesucht ist. Ich wollte nur wissen, ob dieser Satz grammatikalisch/nicht komisch klingt.

Answer (score 2):

Die Antwort von Wolf ist richtig: Der Satz ist, mit der veränderten Kommasetzung, grammatisch korrekt.

Stilistisch ist er allerdings eher holprig. In meinen Ohren klingt es nach einer Übersetzung (vermutlich aus dem Englischen), und ich halte die Formulierung im Deutschen nicht für idiomatisch. Ich meine, dass *machen* im Deutschen etwas mehr Aktivität impliziert. Der *Mut* ist ja aber kein aktiver Agent. Ich meine, dass solche Formulierungen im Englischen üblicher sind - im Deutschen kommt es mir ungebräuchlich vor.

Eine natürlichere Variante, dasselbe zu sagen, wäre etwa:

> Wegen seines Mutes ist es ein bisschen schwierig, ihn zu tolerieren.

Anders sieht es bei tatsächlichen Handlungen aus. Hier scheint mir die Konstruktion auch im Deutschen stilistisch unproblematisch. Etwa in folgendem Beispiel:

> Der andauernde Schneeregen macht die Autobahn schwer zu befahren.

Comment: Danke Ihnen. Ich wusste nichts über die Logik, die diese Ungrammatikalität erklärt. Das war klug!

Comment: Da das englische Original nun per Kommentar nachgeliefert wurde, ist die [etwas frappierende Lesart hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/62028/jemanden-adj-zu-verb-struktur#comment151500_62028) wohl auszuschließen. Man kommt sich schon vor wie beim Scrabble: erst streiten um eine besonders abwegige Beugungsform schließlich doch zu akzeptieren ;-)

Comment: BTW: *Sein Mut macht ihn zum Vorbild*, das ist nicht gerade Alltagssprache, aber solides Deutsch.

Comment: @Wolf Oder man wartet mit einer Antwort, bis die Fragen im Kommentarbereich geklärt sind :) Aber leider werden die Fragen mitunter von den OP gar nicht beantwortet. Insofern bleibt es eine Risikioabwägung :)

Comment: @Wolf Bezüglich _Sein Mut machte ihn zum Vorbild_: Ich stimme dir zu, dass das akzeptabel ist. Hast du eine Idee, wo der Unterschied zum Beispielsatz der Fragestellung liegt? Ich dachte, wie gesagt, dass es daran liegt, dass _Mut_ kein echter Agent ist, aber das wäre ja mit deinem korrekten Beispiel widerlegt.